# How to merge one column from two different file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two file `bla.tsv` (FS=`\t`) and `blo.tsv` (FS=`\t`) generate by the same code.

`bla.tsv`:

```
id hub klos
3 2 bis
2 5 
4 2 bis
5 2 
8 3 
7 2 bis
```

`blo.tsv`:

```
id hub klos
3 2 
2 5 jus
4 2 
5 2 
8 3 jus
7 2
```

And I want to merge the column `klos` from the two in order to have a new file :

```
id hub klos
3 2 bis
2 5 jus
4 2 bis
5 2 
8 3 jus
7 2 bis
```

Precision :

1. all the rest of the file are always the same, only the column `klos` changes between files.
2. it's a subsampling of my real files, my real files have 47 column.
3. It's exactly the same file in term of line and column.
4. for the klos column , when the first file have something write, it's not possible for the other file to have something in this exact same line

I've tried to search online how to merge but only found example for one file, not two. Do you have an idea how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: Are the values in the first 2 fields always numeric or could they start with alphabetic characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{klos[NR]=$3; next} $3==""{$3=klos[FNR]} 1' blo.tsv bla.tsv
id      hub     klos
3       2       bis
2       5       jus
4       2       bis
5       2
8       3       jus
7       2       bis
```